# PHP trim doesn't work in my case

Tags: php

I have the next situation:

```
$a = '   0226  ';
```

I'm trying to remove whitespaces from the beginning and end of the string:

```
print_r(trim($a));
```

and expected output is:

```
'0226'
```

Here are results of `var_dump` and `urlencode` of above string:

```
print_r(urlencode($a)); // %C2%A0+0226+%C2%A0
var_dump($a) // <pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'><small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'  0226  '</font> <i>(length=10)</i>
</pre>
```

Comment: That's not a normal space character that `trim` can work on.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not alter `$a` in any way.

The syntax for a `trim()` is

```
$newvar = trim($originalvar);
```

Contatenating functions like you have means you never actually store the trimmed value anywhere that you can later dump it to check its value.

Try `var_dump`ing the value you actually trimmed

```
$a = '   0226  ';
$b = trim($a);
echo 'Trimmed value = >' . $b . '<';

$c = urlencode($b);
echo 'urlencoded value = >' . $c . '<';
```

Also `print_r()` is for dumping arrays and I dont think any of your code creates or uses an array.

Answer (score 0):

The space preceding the text and after the text isnt a kind of space trim can work on. I think there is more to the space than just what you see.

You could use `htmlspecialchars()` to detect if there are special characters other than spaces before and after the text...